# An algorithm that finds an edge that can be removed to create a tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, tree

Load the graph at the input. This graph started as a tree (i.e. an unoriented graph that does not contain loops) with n vertices numbered 1 to n, to which one edge was added that it did not contain. The input graph is represented as a list of its edges, where a_i b_i says that the graph has an edge between the vertices a_i and b_i.

Program will list which edge we can remove from the graph to create a tree with n vertices from the graph. If more than one answer is possible, answer with the one at the input last.

**For example, to input:**

> 1 2
>
> 1 3
>
> 2 3

Program will answer 2 3

**For input:**

> 1 2
>
> 2 3
>
> 3 4
>
> 1 4
>
> 1 5

Answer 1 4

I have a code that can determine if numbers are a tree, but I don't know how to make it so that they can be entered, and how to make it so that it removes unnecessary edges:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class Graph():
 
    def __init__(self, V):
        self.V = V
        self.graph  = defaultdict(list)
 
    def addEdge(self, v, w):
        
        self.graph[v].append(w)
        
        self.graph[w].append(v)
 
    def isCyclicUtil(self, v, visited, parent):
        visited[v] = True
        for i in self.graph[v]:
            if visited[i] == False:
                if self.isCyclicUtil(i, visited, v) == True:
                    return True
            elif i != parent:
                return True
 
        return False
 
   
    def isTree(self):
        visited = [False] * self.V
        if self.isCyclicUtil(0, visited, -1) == True:
            return False
 
      
        for i in range(self.V):
            if visited[i] == False:
                return False
 
        return True
 

g1 = Graph(5)
g1.addEdge(1, 0)
g1.addEdge(0, 2)
g1.addEdge(0, 3)
g1.addEdge(2, 3)
if g1.isTree() == True:
    print("Tree")
else:
    print("Not Tree")
```

Comment: Doesn't the input format start with the value of *n*??

Comment: Please clarify your statement "I don't know how to make it so that they can be entered, and how to make it so that it removes unnecessary edges:"  What is your question?  What problem do you have?

Comment: @trincot no, all that is, is the vertices that are in the example

Comment: @itprorh66  I need help so that the user can enter data himself, as in the example, and the algorithm removes unnecessary edges to create a tree, because my code only checks if numbers are a tree, but I couldn't make it find unnecessary edges

Comment: Use the python input statement

Answer (score 0):

You can read input from standard input via the `input` function.

Your code currently creates the graph structure, and then determines whether two nodes are connected by walking through the graph with a depth-first traversal.

I would however suggest a slightly more efficient algorithm: instead of creating a graph, create a [disjoint set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets). There are several libraries out there that offer this data structure, but I'll throw my own in the below code.

This structure keeps track of which nodes belong to the same connected group(s).

Then the algorithm becomes simple: for each edge you read from the input, indicate (using the disjoint set interface) that the two involved nodes belong to the *same* set. Before doing that however, check whether they already *are* in the same set. If this happens, stop the algorithm and output this edge.

Here is the generic `DisjointSet` class I will be using:

```
class DisjointSet:
    class Element:
        def __init__(self):
            self.parent = self
            self.rank = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = {}

    def add(self, key):
        el = self.Element()
        self.elements[key] = el
        return el

    def find(self, key, add_if_not_exists=False):
        el = self.elements.get(key, None)
        if not el:
            if add_if_not_exists:
                el = self.add(key)
            return el
        # Path splitting algorithm
        while el.parent != el:
            el, el.parent = el.parent, el.parent.parent
        return el

    def union(self, key=None, *otherkeys):
        if key is not None:
            root = self.find(key, True)
            for otherkey in otherkeys:
                el = self.find(otherkey, True)
                if el != root:
                    # Union by rank
                    if root.rank < el.rank:
                        root, el = el, root
                    el.parent = root
                    if root.rank == el.rank:
                        root.rank += 1
```

And here is the code specific for the problem:

```
def solve():
    visited = DisjointSet()
    while True:
        edge = input().split()
        a = visited.find(edge[0])
        b = visited.find(edge[1])
        if a and a is b:  # This edge creates a cycle
            print(" ".join(edge))
            break  # Stop reading more input
        visited.union(*edge)
```

As you can see, this code *assumes* that the input *will* have an edge that creates a cycle (like is stated in the problem description). So it only has a way to stop the process when such an offending edge is found.

Comment: Perhaps I did something wrong, but when entering the example I provided, a syntax error occurs

Comment: I don't see any problems when inputting the examples you have given. See it run [on repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma705097225459839)